# Getting Compiler Error Expecting '{' but was: '(' at line 1 column 29 for Apex Class

Tags: class, compiler-errors, apex

I am getting Compile Error: Expecting '{' but was: '(' at line 1 column 29. Have had a look at code and looks find to me:

\
Public class pagedirections (){

String recordId = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');

Public PageReference urlRedirection(recordId)
{

Case location;

location = [Select ID, Case_TEXT__c From Case Where ID =:recordId LIMIT 1];

if(location.Case_TEXT__c == 'Australia')

PageReference page = new PageReference('https://www.google.com');

return null;

}

}

\\

Any help on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line, you have used parenthesis for a class declaration which is the wrong syntax.

```
Public class pagedirections (){
```

please remove parenthesis

```
public class pagedirections{
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vignesh Aiyer,